# Setting Snowflake converter_class Still Converts to Python Data Types

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the docs for the python Snowflake connector, it says that setting the connection parameter `converter_class` when creating the connection object can be used to suppress conversion to python types (leaves data as strings).  But I see no difference between queries run with the following two connections (using `snowflake-connector-python=2.7.0`):

```
from snowflake.connector.converter_null import SnowflakeNoConverterToPython

DBH1 = snowflake.connector.connect(
       user='username',
       password='password',
       account='account',
       converter_class=SnowflakeNoConverterToPython      # why isn't this working?
    )

DBH2 = snowflake.connector.connect(
       user='username',
       password='password',
       account='account'
    )
```

Queries executed from both DBH1 and DBH2 return timestamps as python datetime objects, and not strings.  I noticed that in the doc on `snowflake.connector` parameters, there is no mention of a `converter_class` option - this trick is only listed in the "optimizing data pulls" section here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#improving-query-performance-by-bypassing-data-conversion.  Is it possible that this feature has been dropped without cleaning up the doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this feature was added initially it was only meant for **JSON** result set format. Since then we migrated result set to **ARROW** and for this format it doesn't work indeed (**ARROW** is default format now).

To demonstrate I use this code:

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=USER,
        password=PASSWORD,
        account=ACCOUNT,
        role=ROLE,
        database=DATABASE,
        schema=SCHEMA,
        warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
        converter_class=SnowflakeNoConverterToPython
        )

cs = ctx.cursor()

try:
        cs.execute("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")
        res  = cs.fetchone()
        print(f'{res[0]}')
        print(type(res[0]))
        print(isinstance(res[0], str))
```

This returns to me:

```
2021-11-24 21:34:44.314000+13:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
False
```

Now, I change result set format back to original **JSON**:

```
try:
        cs.execute("alter session set python_connector_query_result_format='JSON'")
        cs.execute("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")
```

This time I get:

```
1637742958.657000000
<class 'str'>
True
```

The **ARROW** format has several advantages over **JSON** and you can read more [here](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/fetching-query-results-from-snowflake-just-got-a-lot-faster-with-apache-arrow/)